# A subset S of a vector space is linearly independent iff every vector in S can be written as a unique linear combination of other vector in S

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

> A family $(x_\alpha)_{\alpha \in A}$ of vectors is linearly
>   independent if and only if every vector $x$ can be written in at most
>   one way as a linear combination of $(x_\alpha)$

How can we prove the $\Leftarrow$ part ?

I'm following Werner Geubs' Linear Algebra Book and this proposition is proved in page 10, but I didn't get it what he means by "the scalar $\lambda_\alpha$ is uniquely determined by x".I mean to show the family of the sets is linearly independent, it chooses $x = 0$, but then concluded that the scalars in the unique expression of the linear combination of $x$ are $0$.

Comment: In the header you say "every vector in S" but you don't say that in the statement of the question.  And you have marked as correct an answer that assumes the hypothesis applies to $0$ - were $0\in S$ then $S$ wouldn't be LI..

Comment: @ancientmathematician I just wrote what the book says.If you have counter example, please share.

Comment: It's the question in the header that is wrong for the reason I gave; the one in the main text is OK.

Comment: @ancientmathematician How does the statement in the main question guarantees that the zero vector is not in the family ?

Comment: @Leh: because with $x_1=0$ say we would have the non-unique expression for $x=0\in V$ thus $0=0.x_1 =1. x_1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. Given $(x_\alpha)$, the vector 0 can be written in AT MOST one way as a linear combination of the $(x_\alpha)$. ONE way is with all the coefficients equal to zero. So this is the UNIQUE way.

Comment: Yes, but how does it helps us the conclude that $x = \sum_{\alpha \in A} \lambda_\alpha * x_{\alpha} = 0 \Rightarrow \lambda_\alpha = 0$ =

Comment: Ok, I got it now.Since we have the trivial case, and it has to bu unique, there cannot be any other case.

Comment: Yes. That is right. You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Take $a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 + \dots a_nx_n = 0$

Because, $0*x_1 + 0*x_2 + \dots 0*x_n = 0$, by unicity we have to conclude that $a_1 = a_2 = \dots = a_n = 0$

Hence, the set of vectors is linear independent.